# Load image to navigation drawer in android studio from a URL

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I am trying to load an image into navigation drawer in android studio. But the app keeps closing. I cant figure out why it is happening. The image is of size 697x967.
My navigation drawer xml file looks like:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/profilePic"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@string/nav_header_desc"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"/>
```

and the code in home page looks like the following put under onCreate method.

```
    ImageView profile_pic=findViewById(R.id.profilePic);
    Bundle bundle=getIntent().getExtras();
    String profile_url="https://www.rajagiritech.ac.in/stud/Photo/"+ bundle.getString("username")+".jpg";
    try{
        URL url = new URL(profile_url);
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
        profile_pic.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    }catch(MalformedURLException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }catch(IOException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I have an activity calling this activity and passing the username.

```
public void onClick(View v){
    EditText uid_form=findViewById(R.id.uid_form);
    String uname=uid_form.getText().toString();
    Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),HomePage.class);
    intent.putExtra("username",uname);
    startActivity(intent);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_page);
}
```

Comment: post the log errors please

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Picasso library or Glide library for to load image

```
Picasso.with(context).load("https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEIKP.jpg").into(imageView);
```

**context** : is the Context of the Activity

**https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEIKP.jpg** :url of the Image

**imageView** : is the ImageView in which you want to load the image

Comment: Do you have add the internet permissions?